Ways to prove that the differential of multiplication map is addition
Let $G$ be a group and a smooth manifold. Let
$
\mu : G \times G \to G, \quad (x, y) \mapsto xy
$
be the multiplication map assumed smooth
Prove that the tangent map $d_{(e,e)} \mu : T_e G \times T_e G \to T_e G$ of $\mu$ at $(e, e)$ is given by $(X, Y) \mapsto X + Y$.
To compute $d_{(e,e)} \mu$, consider smooth curves $\alpha(t)$ and $\beta(t)$ in $G$ such that:

$\alpha(0) = e$, $\alpha'(0) = X$
$\beta(0) = e$, $\beta'(0) = Y$

Then, the composition $\gamma(t) = \mu(\alpha(t), \beta(t)) = \alpha(t)\beta(t)$ is a curve in $G$ passing through $e$ at $t = 0$.
Differentiating $\gamma(t)$ at $t = 0$:
$$
\gamma'(0) = \left. \frac{d}{dt} \left( \alpha(t)\beta(t) \right) \right|_{t=0} = \alpha'(0)\beta(0) + \alpha(0)\beta'(0) = Xe + eY = X + Y
$$
Therefore, the tangent map is:
$$
d_{(e,e)} \mu(X, Y) = X + Y
$$
My questions are

Is my approah correct? I am not sure, I have seen this question solved for example here

Differential of the multiplication and inverse maps on a Lie group
in a different way, and couldn't  find any resource where it is solved as I did. If mine is wrong, why? I am specially suspicious about the $Xe =X$ and  $eY=Y$ multiplications, it should't be allowed to multiply elements of the tangent space with those of the manifold, should it?  I read in a forum, however, that it should't be a problem because it is like a left or right translation by e, and the differential of left or right translation (multiplication) by e is the identity linear map. But I am not comfortable with this explanation, as these differentials did not showed up explicitly in my proof.

I found another solution here:


But I don't know what is going on on the next-to-last equality, how is that splited into a sum?

You can't write a priori $\left. \frac{d}{dt} \left( \alpha(t)\beta(t) \right) \right|_{t=0} = \alpha'(0)\beta(0) + \alpha(0)\beta'(0)$ because you have not proven the product rule (this is what you want to prove) and you have not given a meaning to multiplication of tangent vector with an element of the Lie group.
In the tangent algebra $T^{\infty}_e G$ one can indeed multiply $e$ with tangent vectors $X \in T_e G$ (the tangent algebra of $G$ is actually isomorphic to the universal enveloping algebra of the lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$). It holds $Xe = X = eX$ for all $X \in T^\infty_e G$.
But one does not need the tangent algebra for this exercise.
For the second: there is the canonical isomorphism $(d\pi_1, d\pi_2): T_{(a,b)} (G \times G) \to T_a G \times T_b G$, where $\pi_i$ is the canonical projection onto the $i$-th factor. So, it holds by linearity
$$(X_a,Y_b)(f \circ \mu(a,b)) = (X_a,0_b)(f \circ \mu(a,b)) + (0_a,Y_b)(f \circ \mu(a,b)) \\
= ((d\pi_1,d\pi_2)(\left. \frac{d}{dt} \left( \alpha(t),b \right) \right|_{t=0}))(f\circ \mu(a,b)) + ((d\pi_1,d\pi_2)(\left. \frac{d}{dt} \left( a,\beta(t) \right) \right|_{t=0}))(f\circ \mu(a,b)) = \left. \frac{d}{dt} \left( \alpha(t),b \right) \right|_{t=0}(f\circ \mu) + \left. \frac{d}{dt} \left( a,\beta(t) \right) \right|_{t=0}(f\circ \mu) = \left. \frac{d}{dt} \right|_{t=0}(f\circ \mu(\alpha(t),b)) + \left. \frac{d}{dt} \right|_{t=0}(f\circ \mu(a,\beta(t))) = \left. \frac{d}{dt} \right|_{t=0}(f\circ R_b(\alpha(t)) + \left. \frac{d}{dt} \right|_{t=0}(f\circ L_a(\beta(t))) = \left. \frac{d}{dt} \left( \alpha(t) \right) \right|_{t=0}(f\circ R_b) + \left. \frac{d}{dt} \left(\beta(t) \right) \right|_{t=0}(f\circ L_a) \\
= X_a(f\circ R_b) + Y_b(f\circ L_a)$$

Thanks for the answer. Isn't that product rule an ordinary one? Since the domains of the curves are a subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

But the codomain is $G$, so the "product rule" you're thinking of involves a composition with $\mu$ and the chain rule. Namely, to differentiate $\alpha(t)\beta(t)$ you are differentiating $\mu(\alpha(t),\beta(t))$ with the chain rule and applying the formula given in Lemma 1.2 of your screenshot. See my answer for a way around it.

In the second part I am still puzzled about various things. I have no idea how you are using the definitions $dF_p(Z)(g)=Z(g\circ F)$, or $dF_p(Z)(g)=d/dt_{t=0}(F\circ \delta)(t)$, for some curve $\delta$ which I supposed you're using to do all these transformations:...

How do you get $(X_a,0_b)(f \circ \mu(a,b))
= ((d\pi_1,d\pi_2)(\left. \frac{d}{dt} \left( \alpha(t),b \right) \right|{t=0}))(f\circ \mu(a,b)) =\left. \frac{d}{dt} \left( \alpha(t),b \right) \right|{t=0}(f\circ \mu)  = \left. \frac{d}{dt} \right|{t=0}(f\circ \mu(\alpha(t),b))  = \left. \frac{d}{dt} \right|{t=0}(f\circ R_b(\alpha(t)) = \left. \frac{d}{dt} \left( \alpha(t) \right) \right|_{t=0}(f\circ R_b) $

The first equality is the observation $\pi_1(\alpha(t),b) = \alpha(t)$ and $\pi_2(\alpha(t),b) = b$, so derivative at zero is $X_a$ for the first and $0_b$ for the second. The second equality is the canonical isomorphism of the tangent spaces. And the rest the definitions for the differentials you mentioned in the comment above.

You want to compute $$\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\bigg|_{t=0} \alpha(t)\beta(t)$$but, as user psl2Z points out, the "product rule" is not available yet. So we go back to the oldest trick in the book: define $f(t,s) = \alpha(t)\beta(s)$, and note by the chain rule that the desired quantity is the sum $(\partial_tf)(0,0) + (\partial_sf)(0,0)$. Each term is easily computed: $$(\partial_tf)(0,0) = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\bigg|_{t=0} \alpha(t)\beta(0) = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\bigg|_{t=0} \alpha(t)e =\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\bigg|_{t=0} \alpha(t) = X,$$and similarly $(\partial_sf)(0,0) = Y$. So ${\rm d}\mu_{(e,e)}(X,Y) = X+Y$.

1)Why is the chain rule equal to that sum? Wouldn't it be $\partial_t (\alpha(r)\beta(s))=(\partial_t (\alpha(r)))\beta(s))$, which is half of what I want? Or better don't I need to define $f(r,s)=\alpha(r)\beta(s)$, and $r(t)=t, s(t)=t$, so that I get the full expression?


Doesn't the other problem of having a multiplication of a tangent vector by a group element persist?  I take it that $\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\bigg|{t=0} \alpha(t)e$ means $(\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\bigg|{t=0} \alpha(t))e$, so the multiplication is after the derivation.

